# how to save blank spaces in text area

Tags: table, long-text-area

I have a large text area wherein among other things details in following format has to go:

```
Start IP   End IP   Protocol   Start Port    End Port
-------------------------------------------------------
1.1.1.1    3.3.3.3   TCP          8080        8081
```

The space which I am entering in apex using `\t` or `blank spaces` is getting trimmed when the above is saved.

Is that the expected behaviour. What is the way out?

Comment: Adding a CSS, [`white-space: pre;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) changes anything to it?

Comment: I believe when you edit the record you will see the spaces.

Comment: You could also just create field for each of those items and be done with it

Answer (score 2):

I had a client once where the spaces in an External ID mattered (i.e. A..12 B vs A.12 B were different IDs - dots are spaces) and they wanted them to be displayed in SF.

I wrote a utility method to do that for a given field and remove it (replacing with real space) as well when sending back to the external system

```
public static String preserveWhitespace(String s){

    if(s!= null)
        s = s.replace(' ',String.fromCharArray( new Integer[] { 160 }));

    return s;
}

public static String removeChr160(String s){

    String tmp = String.fromCharArray( new Integer[] { 160 });

    if(s != null)
        s = s.replace(tmp, ' ');

    return s;
}
```

This will display multiple spaces in a row in the UI. But keep in mind the impact it could have and test it thoroughly

Comment: N.B. You can do the same with formula fields by pasting in the UTF 'true space' character but commenting the formula is a must as otherwise the next poor admin has no idea what you were doing